# How to convert nested string to list

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert nested string to list

```
    list = '[{"dialog_context": {"dialog_active": "orderno","lifespan": 2,"name": "Order_number_dialog_context","parameters": {"orderno": ""},"prompt": "What is the order number?","time_stamp": 1565256993.914126},"followup_context": 'null',"intent": "Order_number","name": "Order_number_context","parameters_context": null,"timestamp": 1565256993.914128}]'
```

```
eval(list)
```

but i am getting error

```
> File "<string>", line 1, in <module> NameError: name 'null' is not
> defined
```

Comment: If this is json file/payload you should use the `json` module (`json.loads(list)`): https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html . Also, pick a name that doesn't shadow the standard-library (`list` is a bad name).

Answer (score 0):

Given that `'null'` is actually just `null` you can use `json`:

```
import json

mylist = '[{"dialog_context": {"dialog_active": "orderno","lifespan": 2,"name": "Order_number_dialog_context","parameters": {"orderno": ""},"prompt": "What is the order number?","time_stamp": 1565256993.914126},"followup_context": null,"intent": "Order_number","name": "Order_number_context","parameters_context": null,"timestamp": 1565256993.914128}]'

json.loads(mylist)

[{'dialog_context': {'dialog_active': 'orderno',
  'lifespan': 2,
  'name': 'Order_number_dialog_context',
  'parameters': {'orderno': ''},
  'prompt': 'What is the order number?',
  'time_stamp': 1565256993.914126},
  'followup_context': None,
  'intent': 'Order_number',
  'name': 'Order_number_context',
  'parameters_context': None,
  'timestamp': 1565256993.914128}]
```

As you can see, the `null` is being converted to `None`.